# AngularJS filter won't filter values that are equal to 0

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have the following search input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.Kkz">
```

And I have the following ng-repeat:

```
<tr class="ListItem" ng-class-odd="'Odd'" ng-class-even="'Even'"
        ng-repeat="item in Prios | filter:search | filterMultiple:{Sprache:spracheSelectedItem} | orderBy:predicate:reverse | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"
        ng-click="setSelectedRow(item)" ng-class="{'Selected': item == selectedRow}">
```

Currently the Kkz field can have 2 values (3000 and 0). When I search for the number 3000, it returns a correct list. But when I search for the value "0" nothing happens, as if it doesn't find that value in the table column that I am searching.

Comment: Please post the relevant js code from app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the filter looks for a case insensitive substring match. Here it finds the 0 within 3000 so both 3000 and 0 match.

In the case of a simple array of strings you could use `filter:search:true`, in this case where search is an object creating your own comparator can help:

In the HTML add the name of the compare function:

```
... | filter:search:compare | ...
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.compare = function (actual, expected) {
  // !expected: All records pass when no search value is specified.
  // == instead of ===: Coerce the numbers from the array into strings to 
  //                    properly compare to the string from the input. 
    return (!expected || actual == expected);
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your snappy and incredibly accurate answer! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you say nothing happens. What exactly do you mean? Do you still get the same results or no results?

Can it be because when you search for 0 with filter so it also matches 3000?

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="values = [0,555,3000]"></div>

Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<ul ng-repeat="value in values | filter:searchText">
  <li>{{value}}</li>
</li>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/CEt6XKP5ylQtXc2hhsx4?p=preview for a working example of this.

If this is not the case please post more code.